# Как раскодировать строку base64?

Tags: base64, php

вот код:

```
$str = 'DQogICAgT1BFTCBBc2NvbmEsIDEuNtC7INC60LDRgNCxLiwg0YbQsi4g0YHQtdGA0YvQuSwg0LvRjtC6LCDRgtC40YLQsNC90L7QstGL0LUg0LTQuNGB0LrQuCBSLTE0LCDQvNCw0LPQvdC40YLQvtC70LAsINGB0LjQs9C9Liwg0L3QvtCyLiDQsNC60LrRg9C80YPQu9GP0YLQvtGALCDQsdC40LrRgdC10L3QvtC9LCAyNTAwMNCz0YDQvS4sINGC0L7RgNCzLCDQstC 0LfQvC4g0L7QsdC80LXQvSDQvdCwINCwL9C8INCS0JDQlyAyMTA5LCAi0LrQu9GO0Ycg0L3QsCDQutC70Y7RhyIuIAkoMDYzKTUzOTY3NTEsICgwOTYpNDM0MDMyMQ==';
echo base64_decode($str);
```

Вроде все правильно, а на выходе ничего нету((

Как это лечится?

Comment: @oleg777, в закодированной base64 строке не бывает пробелов. Подозреваю, что тут две строки, первая в юникоде, вторая не знаю в чем.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ в комментарий не влезает.

В строке много мусора.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ base64 -di t

    OPEL Ascona, 1.6л карб., цв. серый, люк, титановые диски R-14, магнитола, сигн., нов. аккумулятор, биксенон, 25000грн., торг, вд-�/
                                                       �4/�,t/4-t/H4/t4,
                                                                        �4$�$4%�
��.�.�c�a�4/t4.�.�c�aȋ�J
��ML�M��LK

M�M
   �

    base64: invalid input
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

вот что получилось в UTF-8.